# MVC 4 Connection String

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I everyone,

Lately im learning the MVC 4 and need someone who could explain to me how the connection string work, because I started to create new records in the application but when i access the database(microsoft sql server 2012), the new records arent shown but they are on the application. I've check the app_data but there isnt any mdf file.

Here is the connectino String:

```
<add name="Tusofona" connectionString="Server=Macieira-PC;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=nippon;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks fine - but it's pointing to a real instance of SQL Server, not a standalone file in App_Data, so make sure you're looking at your actual database.

You're pointed to `master` though, which is a bad idea. You should create a new database, and point to that one instead.

Comment: the master database its only for example. Why i cannot use the database data?

Comment: Try debugging your data access code - when you create your connection, look at the connection string to make sure it matches this one. If so, and your app appears to be functioning properly, then the data is making it to your database, so just open Management Studio and point it to this database, and your data will be there.